# How can I "hook into" Python from C++ when it executes a function? My goal is to profile

Tags: c++, python, profiling

I'm implementing a profiler in an application and I'm a little flummoxed about how to implement Python profiling such that the results can be displayed in my existing tool. The application allows for Python scripting via communication with the python interpreter.

I was wondering if anyone has ideas on how to profile Python functions from C++

Thank you for your suggestions :)

Comment: Is there are particular reason for profiling *from C++*?  It might be easier to decorate your functions with a decorator that times execution and registers each call with the profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Well not sure what your goal is, but I'd personally not start from zero but use the existing modules for profiling. The cprofile module was written in C and should be easily extensible if the documentation is to be believed: http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/profile.html#extensions-deriving-better-profilers

Comment: Thank you, but how can I derive it in C++.

I should be more clear. The tool I'm writing is in C++ and the app it profiles is also written in c++ and scripting can be done in Python. So my goal is to time those Python scripts using just my tool.

Comment: In that case how do you invoke the scripts? If the user just specifies a script and you let that run, I think you could implement a small python stub that does `cProfile.run(import Module)` or something similar. Then you can use the returned stats from the call to do whatever you want. Would be a python solution, but since cProfile is written in C, I'm pretty sure you could also call it directly from C++.

Comment: Now that's an idea. The scripts are executed by the users (the application allows users to 'source' scripts and run them). How would I call cProfile from c++? I can't find any docs on this (maybe my google-fu is weak)....

Comment: Haven't tried that myself (ie calling c functions of the python API from C itself) and on a second glance I see at least one problem: Python defines all methods static and uses a PyMethodDef structure to access them via function pointers. Now I'm sure you can somehow get to that pointer and initialize everything yourself, you'd make your job MUCH easier just calling the python function cProfile.run() with the correct arguments.

Comment: You should probably ask a second question if you need more information on how to do the second possibility (initializing a PythonInterpreter and then calling a method from it). The documentation is sadly lacking and I'd be glad to help there - it's not much code and MUCH simpler than the other way.. though I'm sure some gurus here or on the python mailing list could help with that as well.

Comment: Will do, thanks Voo :) The new thread is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034334/calling-a-method-from-a-python-interpreter

Answer (score 0):

The usual technique for profiling already-existing functions that we use in Lua a lot is to overwrite the function with your own version that will start timing, call the original function, and stop timing, returning the value that the original function returned.

Comment: Thanks, but the existing script base is quite a lot of Python scripts, so I'm not sure how my customer would react to me telling them to make manual changes.

Comment: @easythrees you overwrite them from C++, not by making manual changes.